# Listen for notification on React Native app from Django server

Tags: android, ios, django, react-native, notifications

I'm currently developing a programme that will need app developers to listen out for a (ideally) silent notification from my Django server. Right now, I'm testing with a React Native app I've made but I don't know how to implement something like this. Basically, when something happens in relation to a certain app on the server end of things, I want to send a notification to that client app to react accordingly. Almost like a webhook but for mobile.

It's important to know that in practice, I won't be the owner and developer of both the client-side app and the server-side software, just the server-side. If anyone knows how to do it natively on either Android or iOS that would be appreciated too.

Comment: You can use websockets: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: Thanks @kamran890 That looks like it will do the trick!

Comment: Be aware that on ios at least, websockets disconnect as soon as your app moves to the background. The only way to deliver events to an iOS app that isn't in the foreground is via push notifications.